# Python Date and Time

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that will return variable value depending on date and time. I am trying to create a small competition every month and the competition starts from 15th of one month  and ends 15th of next month. If the competition is starting from Jan 15 and ending on Feb 15 then the function should return end date and time which is (Feb 15, 2020 24:00:00) and competition name which is "January 2020". How can i do this any suggestions?

For instance:

```
def CompetitionDetail():
 #doing something here
 return competition_end_date, competition_name
```

Comment: What did you try to do so far? Can you share the code you wrote?

Comment: Have you tried to import the 'import datetime` module and use `datetime.datetime.now()` to capture the current date and time, then use `strftime("%m")` to find the month? If you want to learn more, see examples and materials here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question, I came up with the following below. The returns are the start and end date/times of the competition that begins on the 15th of the current month and ends on the 15th of the following month. The function accepts a date but uses today's date if no date is specified.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def competition(date=date.today()):
    fifteenth_this_month = datetime(date.year, date.month, 15, 23, 59, 59)
    fifteenth_next_month = datetime(date.year, date.month + 1, 15, 23, 59, 59)

    competition_name = f'My awesome competition for the month of ' \
                       f'{fifteenth_this_month:%B %Y}.'
    
    competition_ending = f'This awesome competition ends on ' \
                         f'{fifteenth_next_month:%b %d, %Y} at 24:00:00.'
    
    print(competition_name, competition_ending, '', sep='\n')
    
    return fifteenth_this_month, fifteenth_next_month
```

OUTPUT

```
 My awesome competition for the month of August 2020.
 This awesome competition ends on Sep 15, 2020 at 24:00:00.

(datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 15, 23, 59, 59), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 15, 23, 59, 59))
```